# The usage frequency of individual English words

Tags: computational-linguistics, frequency

I'm very new to NLP and I'm sure this question is a rookie one. In NLP for English language, how do we tell if a word is commonly used, from one that is not commonly used? What is the simplest measure? e.g., in a NLP application for children's bedtime story the need is to avoid uncommon words.

Many thanks. BTW, this is my first question in this forum.

Comment: Simply investigate a corpus (i.e. a large collection of text) and extract the word frequencies. The higher the frequency, the more often it is used.

Comment: Of course, you then need to be sure what you mean by a word, i.e. lemmas (word = its underlying "dictionary form") or inflected word forms like *child* - *children*, *go* - *goes*, counted as separate words. You're probably more interested in lemmas.

Comment: A good, since easy-to-use tool to start with is Python's NLTK library, which also comes with a [book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) providing explanations and exapmles.